# CordApp lifecycle

Tags: lifecycle, corda

Is there any supported way of Corda to roll out changes of a CordApp to all nodes which have an older version? Or how would I distribute even a new CordApp ?

Ideally without having everybody (each affected node owner) to do anything.

Right now it would mean update dependency in gradle , rebuild and restart node, which is rather inconvinient when my node is part of many business networks.

Is there any plan to have something analog to WebServer like tomcat where I could deploy a war file ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not that you do not need to run `deployNodes` to create the new CorDapp JAR. Instead, you can use the Gradle `jar` command:

- Unix/Mac OSX: `./gradlew jar`
- Windows: `gradlew.bat jar`

This will create the new CorDapp JAR under `build/libs`. You then install the new CorDapp by adding the new CorDapp JAR to the `cordapps` folder of every node that will be using the new CorDapp.

As of Corda 3, to pick up the new CorDapp, the node has to be restarted (in the future, we expect Corda to support hot-reloading of CorDapps). There are several considerations here:

- If you are upgrading one or more existing flows:

  - You should [drain the node's currently running flows](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#flow-drains)
  - The flow doesn't have to be upgraded at once on every node, as long as the flow changes you make are [backwards-compatible](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#how-do-i-ensure-flow-backwards-compatibility). You will simply encounter an error if you communicate with another node in the context of a flow for which they have not yet installed a responder
  - See the [docs on upgrading flows](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#flow-versioning) for more details
- If you are upgrading one or more existing states or contracts:

  - You need to keep both the old and new state and contract definitions on the classpath at once (e.g. `IOUState` and `IOUStateV2`)
  - The states and contracts don't have to be upgraded on every node at once. You will simply encounter an error if you send another node a state or contract for which they do not have the definition
  - See the [docs on upgrading contracts and states](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#contract-and-state-versioning) for more details
- If you're using zone constraints for your CorDapp's contracts, you need to update the compatibility zone's network parameters

  - This step is not required if you're using hash constraints or the signature constraints being introduced in Corda 4

Comment: This works for my nodes, but what about the other nodes in the network ?
Drain all flows (or wait until all flows are finished) might be impractical in heavy traffic networks. Any plan to have something like a blue-green deployment ? Or a versioning concept of both CordApps / Flows which allows multiple of them live together ?

Comment: Updated my answer above to address your further questions. I'm not sure what blue-green is :)